# play multiple sounds concurrently using playsound

Tags: python

I have a program that calls a function that is supposed to play a sound immediately after invocation. Sometimes the duration inbetween the function calls is smaller than the duration of the sound itself, in which case i would like for the sounds to overlap. Here is my current approach:

```
from playsound import playsound
import threading
import os

playdq = []

def run_play_sound():
    for i in range(2):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=play_sound, args=(), daemon = True)
        thread.start()

def play_sound():
    while True:
        if len(playdq)!=0:
            o = playdq.pop()
            playsound(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),o+".mp3"))

def play():
    if len(playdq)==0:
        playdq.append("soundname")


run_play_sound()
```

Unfortunately this approach is slightly laggy and the sounds are not immediately played when the "play" function is called. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: When i run your code, nothing happens. What does the `play()` function do? I dont see it called anywhere.

Comment: it is called from a program running seperately which simply imports this as a module and calls the play function multiple times, you would also need an mp3 called "soundname" in the same directory for this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using pygame mixer worked for this purpose